# psexec.exe doesn't work when I create a Process from C#

Tags: c#, process, psexec

Long story short...

This doesnt work:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"External\PsExec.exe";
string file = String.Concat(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,"temp"),@"\iisreset",DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy-hhmmssss"),".txt");
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-s -u {0}\\{1} -p {2} \\\\{3} iisreset > \"{4}\"", Domain,UserName, Password, machineIP, file);
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

I'm getting a RPC Unavailable message.

But when I access the command line in the program folder, then i run this: (with the correct parameters), exactly like I specified in the filename/arguments...

```
External\PsExec.exe -s -u [user] -p [password] \\[ip] iisreset > "[path]"
```

It works! 
Do I have to specify anything else in the C# Process ? What could be possibly happening?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: It works if I put `cmd` as the FileName and `/c PsExec.exe` before the arguments. The problem is this way it always show the window.

Comment: Have you inspected `p.StartInfo.Arguments` in debug to ensure they do exactly match what you are typing into the command line?  Also, is your code running under the same credentials as your command line?

Comment: Yes they match. Could the code be possibly running against different credentials? I thought it could only be my current logged user.

Comment: I think the key problem is that you can't redirect output generated by a process on another machine.

Comment: The process is local, I dunno how psexec does its thing so I can't know for sure why the `cmd /c` version works instead of spitting psexec standard output (which is the exit code of the process it ran)

Comment: it works because cmd.exe does its own separate argument parsing when you pass a /c command to it; cmd.exe knows what to do with a > on the command line, psexec does not. As for the window; you need a console window to run a console app so CreateNewWindow won't work. Try WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redirect standard output using the arguments the way you are doing. That's not how things actually work.

At the command line, your arguments end when the command interpreter sees the >, and it begins the process of redirecting standard output to the filename.

To accomplish this in C# you need to use the `RedirectStandardOutput` property of the `StartInfo` class, then read from the `Process.StandardOutput` stream and write to a file.

The MSDN documentation for [RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) has a short example you can use to get started.

Comment: The thing is, if I use RedirectStandardOutput to redirect the output, I get psexec output which is not what I want. I want the output from the psexec command, which I can get writing that in the command line. Check my edit, I managed to do it but I think it's not the right way.

Comment: I guess I'm confused; are you trying to "run iisreset on a remote system and capture the output to a local file", or "run iisreset and capture the output to a file, all on a remote system"?

Comment: "run iisreset on a remote system and capture the output to a local file"

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using p.startinfo.arguments use p.standardinput.writeline(command)

```
string PSPath = @"C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe";
            fullcommand = PSPath + " -u " + userName + " -p " + password + " \\\\" + remoteMachine + " -h cmd.exe /c " + command + "";
            

            Console.Clear();
            //Console.WriteLine(fullcommand);
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            //process.StartInfo.Arguments = fullcommand;

            process.Start();
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(fullcommand);
            process.StandardInput.Flush();
            process.StandardInput.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("*****Command*****");
            Console.WriteLine(fullcommand);
            Console.WriteLine("*****Output*****");
            Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine("*****Error*****");
            Console.WriteLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine("*****Exit*****");
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine("Again ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iisreset [machinename] -
```

you don't need psexec